# How do I update all documents in a collection with pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm using pymongo (python 3.6 with mlab), and I want to update all the documents in my collection.
in my documents, I have data stored like this :

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5981a77e1d41c81419b60414"
},
"Ticker": "GOOGL",
"Sector": "USTECH",
"Market": "NASDAQ",
"Data": [
    {
        "Date": "Jul 27, 2017",
        "Price": "966.41",
        "Open": "969.52",
        "High": "969.52",
        "Low": "963.50",
        "Vol": "743.92K",
        "Change%": "0.11"
    },
    {
        "Date": "Jul 26, 2017",
        "Price": "965.31",
        "Open": "972.78",
        "High": "973.95",
        "Low": "960.23",
        "Vol": "2.22M",
        "Change%": "-0.38"
    }]}
```

And I want to update all the dates so they look like this :
1997-1-6 instead of Jan 06, 1997.
I have this code :

```
connection = MongoClient(link)
dbase = connection[db_name]
collection = dbase.historicals
client = collection.find()
if client:  
    collection.update({}, "$set" : {"Data.Date":datetime.strptime('Date', '%b %d, %Y').date()})

connection.close()
```

I have tried update_many, but it seems the whole update syntax is not correct, like if it doesn't get acess to the Date field. Any tips ?

Edit : when I try this code :

```
client = collection.update_many({}, {"$set": {"Data": {"Date": '2000'}}})
```

it works, but this one doesn't
    `client = collection.update_many({}, {"$set": {"Data": {"Date": datetime.strptime("Date", '%b %d, %Y').date()}}})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing that "Data" from your update query and add {} before and after "$set"

```
collection.update({}, {"$set" : {"Date":datetime.strptime('Date', '%b %d, %Y').date()}})
```

Comment: Thank you for replying !
It still doesn't work, but when I replace datetime.strptime("Date", '%b %d, %Y').date() with any string, it works,
I think it does't accept operations inside update ?

Comment: would you please tell what error you are getting? so that I can help you if possible

Comment: No syntax error, its like if datetime.strptime doesn't work in crud operations. 
Im using a 
try:

except:
print("error"), so basically it always jumps to this exception, whenever I use 
" datetime.strptime('Date', '%b %d, %Y').date()" 
But it works perfectly when I update with normal strings.

Comment: try to print that exception e and try to resolve that exception because datetime operation in crud will work.. check this documentation  http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html

Comment: This documentation may help you.. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/